# Extending on-premises active directory to Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have hosted my asp.net application on an Azure VM.

My project requirement is to connect it to on-premises database. So, I will be setting up a Site-to-Site VPN.

Also, I need to access on-premises active directory. So for that Ii41 have to extend on-premises active directory to the cloud.

1. But i am still confused because [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) article says hybrid connections do not support **LDAP** and **active directory**
2. If it is possible to extend active directory to azure, does this mean there will be single active directory on azure vm? and how do i manage different users from different on-premises active directories i.e. if a user tries to login from different VPN would he be allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are things you might want to try, since you mention multiple directories from on-premises.

1. Setup AD in Azure, for example: domain.com
2. Add the application inside your Azure AD
3. Go to the on-premise ADs and install the Azure AD Sync wizard application
4. Start syncing ADs to Azure AD, you should be able to see users in Azure AD after this
5. Go back to the application and start configuration the application manifest, you can download and update if you want

The goal here is to gather all the users from different on-premise ADs and let the application use the Azure AD SSO Authentication configured in Azure.